# Where can I get documentation for older versions of PrimeNg?

Tags: angular, primeng, primeng-datatable

I'm enhancing an older application that uses primeng under Angular2.  I wanted to use MultiSelect and DataTable, but customization for these two modules relies on `<ng-template>` which was only introduced in Angular4.

Since Angular4 was released in November 2017, I downloaded primeng version 4.3 which was released in October 2017, built the application and ran the showcase.

When I hit localhost:4200, **the documentation is exactly the same as the current version**.

Several users attempted to mark this as duplicate.  However, the previous answer merely states to download and run the showcase which is what I did.  The showcase still states that ng-template is used to customize the control, but ng-template was not introduced until Angular4, one month after the release of primeng version 4.3.

Comment: check this link for data table this might help you https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/datatable

Comment: That's the documentation I'm referring to.  It says:  Index of the row is available at the ng-template.


    <p-column>
        <ng-template let-car="rowData" let-i="rowIndex" pTemplate="body">
            <button type="button" pButton (click)="selectCar(i)" icon="fa-search"></button>
        </ng-template>
    </p-column>

Comment: Apparently, the bump in primeng versions corresponds to the version of Angular it targets.  To return to an Angular 2 version of primeng, you need to revert to a 2.X version of primeng.  The last was 2.0.6 on April 12, 2017.   https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/releases/tag/2.0.6

Comment: Also, a warning.  Running npm install + ng serve does not work on version 2.0.6.  *sigh*  But you can still dig through the html files under showcase to find information.

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find an off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow. The question is closed as a duplicate and should remain closed. Otherwise it will just get closed as off-topic.